# to read entire the table in peewee

Tags: python, peewee

I have this code in mysql:

```py
def get_table():
    cur = self.cnn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM table")
    data = cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()
    return data
```

that returns the entire table, as a list. And then I can use it in another module to fill a TreeView (tkinter):

```py
for row in data:
    TreeView.insert('',END,text=row[0], values=(row[1],row[2],row[3],etc
```

And this works well. But now I want to do it using Peewee, and I don't know how to return to the module that uses the TreeView the whole table. I thought about doing the below, but that doesn't work.

```py
def get_table():
    for row in Students.select():
       data = data + row.get()
    return data
```

I guess I should try to make a matrix from the data in each row, but I don't know how to do it.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_table():
    return list(Students.select())
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.